# Create module instance inside class __init__?

Tags: python-2.7, methods, module, initialization, instance

I had this class inherit the curves class and called it with a super(), but the code in the module got much too long so i decided to separate them. However I still need to pass initialization variables to the module that was once its parent. I normally assign all module instances to variables outside of the class. However, because I need to pass variables initialized in **init** to the module curves, the only way I can do it is defining it in **init** and creating an instance variable instead of a global variable.

Is this a standard or OK way to do this? or is there a better method to accomplish this.
(the variable is the last line of code **self.crvs = neo_curves.Curves(self.axis, self.safemode)**

```
from pymel.core import *
import neo_name
import neo_curves

nc = neo_name.Name()

class Proxy(object):
    """Contains methods to create a generic proxy chain. Used as a blueprint
    to create more specific types of chains, such as an arm, spine, or leg.

    Keyword Arguments:
    name -- (list) names for the chain
    axis -- (string) axis at which rig is created, e.g. yz
    safemode -- (boolean) determines whether scene nodes will be locked or not.
    """

    def __init__(self, name=['proxy'], axis='yz', safemode=True):
        self.customname = name
        self.axis = axis
        self.safemode = safemode
        self.crvs = neo_curves.Curves(self.axis, self.safemode)
```

Comment: Side question for the readers: is that default argument of `name=['proxy']` going to point to the same mutable list for all instances of the class that do not define their own object for the `name` kwarg?

Comment: @erewok Oh, yes it will. I have a module that names objects in a scene, and it needs several arguments, prefix, name, type, and side. I pass the name to this class and it will create objects with whatever name i give to the instance. I gave those defaults because yz is the default axis of the scene, 'safemode' is something that will restrict editing, and that will be by default on, and 'proxy' is what it is creating. Most of the time it will probably be overwritten, i just decided to put defaults.

Comment: Fair enough: it looks like a famous Python gotcha, which should appear any time that parameter is left off of the instantiation: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments

Comment: @erewok Honestly the defaults on many of the things will most likely be removed in the future, its just easier for testing when i call things. At its current state i'm not running anything complex, just testing the methods that do very basic things.